# Random ID/Number Generator in PHP

Tags: php, random

I am building a list of "agent id's" in my database with the following requirements:

1. The ID must be 9 digits long (numeric only)
2. The ID may not contain more than 3 of the same number.
3. The ID may not contain more than 2 of the same number consecutively (i.e. 887766551; cannot have 888..)

So far I have part 1 down solid but am struggling with 2 and 3 above. My code is below.

```
function createRandomAGTNO() {
    srand ((double) microtime( )*1000000);
    $random_agtno = rand(100000000,900000000);
    return $random_agtno;
}

// Usage
$NEWAGTNO = createRandomAGTNO();
```

Any ideas?

Comment: One micro-optimization...  Bind your `rand` call from `100112233` to `998877665` (The lowest and highest possible matches, so you cut out a lot of un-necessary tries)...

Comment: +1 good thinking ircmaxell! ..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Do *not* re-seed the RNG on every call like that, unless you want to completely blow the security of your random numbers.
2. Unless your PHP is very old, you probably don't need to re-seed the RNG at all, as PHP seeds it for you on startup and there are very few cases where you need to replace the seed with one of your own choosing.
3. If it's available to you, use `mt_rand` instead of `rand`. My example will use `mt_rand`.

As for the rest -- you could possibly come up with a very clever mapping of numbers from a linear range onto numbers of the form you want, but let's brute-force it instead. This is one of those things where yes, the theoretical upper bound on running time is infinite, but the *expected* running time is bounded and quite small, so don't worry too hard.

```
function createRandomAGTNO() {
  do {
    $agt_no = mt_rand(100000000,900000000);
    $valid = true;
    if (preg_match('/(\d)\1\1/', $agt_no))
      $valid = false; // Same digit three times consecutively
    elseif (preg_match('/(\d).*?\1.*?\1.*?\1/', $agt_no))
      $valid = false; // Same digit four times in string
  } while ($valid === false);
  return $agt_no;
}
```

Comment: My gut instinct says eiww due to the regex in the loop.  But then again, they are both light regexes, and you save multiple `rand` calls (even the `array_rand` and `shuffle` functions call it multiple times internally) for each "try"...  So it doesn't appear to be nearly as bad as instinct implies (In fact, it looks to be quite good)... +1...

Comment: I'd say doing it mathematically would be the fastest. Regex can't beat it.

Comment: Try it.  The regex solution posted above averages to 0.00006 seconds per run, and yours averages to 0.00017 seconds (I'm getting about 0.00015 for mine)...  Oh, the average is over a total of 100000 runs each. So in terms of shear speed, it looks like regex takes the cake...

Comment: @ircmaxell it works because nine times out of ten, my whole loop only runs *once* :)

Comment: @hobbs: quite true.  But the difference between 100 light loops and one heavy one is still not insignificant.  So I think it boils down to the regex's being lighter than the `rand` call.  If it was the other way around, another method would be "faster".  But at these speeds, who really cares (unless you're generating billions of them)...

Comment: @hobbs - your code returns the following error: Warning: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: No ending delimiter '/' found in C:\xampp\htdocs\dd.php on line 6

Comment: @JM4 simply change the two regex's to: `'/(\d)\1\1/'` and `'/(\d).*?\1.*?\1.*?\1/'`...

Comment: @hobbs - thanks, works great. Thanks for help as well ircmaxell

Answer (score 1):

For second condition, you can create an array like this

```
$a = array( 0,0,1,1,2,2,3,3.....,9,9 );
```

and get random elements: array_rand() (see manual) to get digit, append it to your ID and remove value from source array by unsetting at index.

Generally, this solving also third condition, but this solution excludes all ID's with possible and acceptable three digits

Comment: [`shuffle`](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php) and [`array_shift`](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php) / [`array_pop`](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.array-pop.php) are a viable alternative to `array_rand` and unsetting indexes.

Answer (score 0):

The first solution that comes to mind is a recursive function that simply tests your three requirements and restarts if any three of them fail. Not the most efficient solution but it would work.  I wrote an untested version of this below.  May not run without errors but you should get the basic idea from it.

```
function createRandomAGTNO(){
  srand ((double) microtime( )*1000000);
  $random_agtno = rand(100000000,900000000);

  $random_agtno_array = explode('', $random_agtno);

  foreach($random_agtno_array as $raa_index => $raa){
    if($raa == $random_agtno_array[$raa_index + 1] && raa == $random_agtno_array[$raa_index + 2]) createRandomAGTNO();

    $dup_match = array_search($raa, $random_agtno_array);
    if($dup_match){
      unset($random_agtno_array[$dup_match]);
      if(array_search($raa, $random_agtno_array)) createRandomAGTNO();
    };
  }

  return $random_agtno;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
<?php
function createRandomAGTNO() {
    //srand ((double) microtime( )*1000000);
    $digits = array( 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0 ,1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0 );
    shuffle($digits);
    $random_agtno = 0;
    for($i = 0; $i < 9; $i++)
    {
        if($i == 0)
        {
            while($digits[0] == 0)
                shuffle($digits);
        }
        /*if($i >= 2)
        {
            while(($random_agtno % 100) == $digits[0])
                shuffle($digits);
        }*/
        $random_agtno *= 10;
        $random_agtno += $digits[0];
        array_splice($digits, 0, 1);
    }
    return $random_agtno;
}

for($i = 0; $i < 1000; $i++)
{
    $NEWAGTNO = createRandomAGTNO();
    echo "<p>";
    echo $NEWAGTNO;
    echo "</p>";
}
?>
```

Good luck!

Edit:
Removed the call to srand() and commented-out the "if($i >= 2)" code, which is impossible anyway, here.

Comment: The advantage here is that; 1) You're not using string/chars but numbers only. 2) You use the shuffle() command which is built in PHP, thus fast. I don't think you really need to use srand(), now that I see.. :)

Comment: Hi ircmaxell, I can't really get what you mean. Check the updated code. Look for an output, out of the 1000 numbers, that violates the rules, because I can't find.

Comment: As for triple digits - if this code takes digits from the above array how comes we get 3 times the same digit?

Comment: Oversight on my point.  But it also doesn't live up to the requirement that a digit can appear up to three times (and as such will only generate a small sub-set of the possible numbers)...

Comment: Are you sure? Can anyone else confirm ircmaxell's argument?

Comment: Oh, I see. My code will make sure a digit doesn't appear more than two times. My bad, misunderstood - asking this in Hebrew would avoid it (: . Should be very easy to fix though, I leave that to the OP practice (:

Comment: @Poni - were you removing user comments? It is very difficult to follow the thread here

Comment: Of course not. Basically what you got from me here is this: An algorithm, which you can optimize, which follows your rules EXCEPT for one thing: Rule #2. Instead of 3 allowable digits of the same here the code will limit to two, of the same. It should be very easy to fix. Play with it, if it doesn't work for you I accept cash & c-card for a complete solution (: .. For real, if doesn't work for you just say so.