# How to protect user_id(auto increment) in URL's

Tags: encryption

Just trying to do some security on my website and trying to figure out the best route to secure an ID.
EXAMPLE: localhost/page.php?user_id=1 TO: localhost/share/df9sdf87423498asf9

Answer (score 0):

You can look into using [UUID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) instead of auto-increment user ids.

Edit:

To be clear, this is by no means "encryption". It is simply an alternative way to using `1,2,3,4...` as primary key for users' table. Bare in mind that using UUID instead of incremental numbers will result in higher I/O because insertions are going in random locations in the index tree, not sequentially as the incremental ids.

Answer (score 0):

That's not security, that's security by obscurity.

Proper security requires that on your server side in page.php, verify that the currently authenticated user has access to the given ID.

If you don't use authentication and pages are only intended to be viewed once, check the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3347521/random-id-number-generator-in-php) for a random number generator.